# execute subscriber in new thread rxandroid

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-android, notifydatasetchanged

I'm currently trying to implement rxandroid in my app to update an adapter.
The only problem is that when i call the adapter.notiyDataSetChanged() the app freezes until the method has finished.

this is what i've done so far:

```
private Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber = new Subscriber<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object o) {

           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }
};
```

...

and then i do the subscribe inside the onResume

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MObservable.getInstance().getObservable()
            .delay(2000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,Schedulers.trampoline())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

and the unsubscribe inside onPause.

The events are triggered in a service that stars the process various times per minute.

So finally my question is: is there any way to not freeze the app while the notify method is called? is the notify executing on a new thread in my code or the subscribeOn is still making notify running on the main thread (as i suspect).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is with `Schedulers.trampoline()` fragment.

From documentation of [`Schedulers.trampoline()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html#trampoline()):

> Creates and returns a Scheduler that queues work on the current thread to be executed after the current work completes.

On Android it means the current `Thread` from main `Thread`.

Remove this parameters and see how `Observable` behaves.